# What mean $ in $PS1 envoriment variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For example, if I check `$PS1` variable I get it:

```
[root@ENGDADOS ~]# echo $PS1
[\u@\h \W]\$
```

But if I reenter this exact variable, it changes from `#` (root) to `$` (usually normal user)

```
[root@ENGDADOS ~]# export PS1="[\u@\h \W]\$ "
[root@ENGDADOS ~]$
```

How to reenter this envoriment variable without change from `#` to `$`? where is this configuration?

Answer (score 3):

The `$` character has special meaning inside double quotes, and other contexts, where it is used for parameter (variable) and command expansion. In these contexts, `\` is used for escaping special characters, that is, interpreting them literally. For example:

```bash
$ a="1 2"
$ b="0 $a 3"
$ echo "$b"
0 1 2 3
$ b="0 \$a 3"
$ echo "$b"
0 $a 3
```

In order to include the literal string `\$` at the end of `PS1` you must either use single quotes to disable special shell constructs  or escape both `\` and `$`.

```bash
$ PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$'
$ PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\\$"
```

If you're using Bash I'd suggest using `declare -p` to inspect a variable, as it could also include trailing whitespace which you won't notice when using `echo`.

```bash
[root@hostname ~]# declare -p PS1
declare -- PS1="[\\u@\\h \\W]\\\$ "
```

In Bash `PS1` is generally defined in the `~/.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes.

Compare:

```
root@d313d6954dee:/# echo '\u@\h:\w\$ '
\u@\h:\w\$
root@d313d6954dee:/# echo "\u@\h:\w\$ "
\u@\h:\w$
```